# Existence of a continuous surjective function $f : \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ for arbitrary $m,n$.

Tags: general-topology, functions, metric-spaces

Let $m,n \in \{ 1, 2, ..., k,... \}$. An interesting question in Topology is to prove the existence of   a continuous surjective function
 $$f : \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n,$$
for arbitrary $m,n$. Then we may consider three cases:

1) If $m = n$, we can take the function $f(x) = x$,  where  $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$;

2) If $m > n$, we can take the projection $\pi(x_1,...,x_m) = (x_1,...,x_n)$ 
which is continuous and surjective;

3) If $m < n$, we have a more delicate case.

In what follows, we present my (incomplete) attempt to solve $3)$. The initial analogy is to think in Peano's function:

$$ P: I \rightarrow I \times I $$

where $I = [0, 1]$ . $P$ is continuous and surjective. However, 
the next step is "to extend" $P$ to obtain at least a continous and surjective function $\tilde{P} : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$. At this point I 
 appreciate any suggestions ! Thanks.

Comment: Peano's example starts on one corner of the square and ends in the opposite. You can append them to cover a tessellation of the plane by unit squares.

Answer (score 1):

For $n = 2$ one method to do it is as in conditionalMethod's comment. An alternative proof goes like this.

Obviuosly it is sufficient to consider the case $m = 1, n > 1$.

We know that there exists a continuous surjection $P  : I \to I^2 = I \times I$. Hence we get continuous surjections $P_n : I \to I^n$ for all $n \ge 2$ by defining inductively $P_n : I \stackrel{P}{\rightarrow} I \times I \stackrel{P_{n-1} \times id }{\rightarrow} I^{n-1} \times I = I^n$. Composing with homeomorphism this gives us continuous surjections $S^k_n : [2k,2k+1] \to [-k,k]^n$ for all $k \in \mathbb N$. Now define
$$S : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^n, S(x) = \begin{cases}
S^0_n(0) & x \le 0 \\
S^k_n(x) & x \in  [2k,2k+1] \\
l^k_n(x) & x \in  [2k+1,2k+2]
\end{cases}
$$
where $l^k_n : [2k+1,2k+2] \to \mathbb R^n$ is any path such that $l^k_n(2k+1) = S^k_n(2k+1)$ and $l^k_n(2k+2) = S^{k+1}_n(2k+2)$.

**Edited:**

We can save the exception $k=0$ in which $[-k,k]^n = [-0,0]^n = \{ 0 \}$. Simply consider the maps $S^k_n$ for $k \ge 1$ and define

$$S : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^n, S(x) = \begin{cases}
S^1_n(0) & x \le 2 \\
S^k_n(x) & x \in  [2k,2k+1] \\
l^k_n(x) & x \in  [2k+1,2k+2]
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Thanks for your hint. However, I do not understand why $S_{n}^{0}(0)$  is well defined, since $S_n^{0}(0) $ is to map $[0, 1] \rightarrow [-0, 0]^n$ (?)

Comment: $[-0,0]^n$ is the set containing only $0 \in \mathbb R^n$. Thus  $S^0_n$ is the constant map. But in fact $k = 0$ is an exception, $[-0,0]^n$ is not homeomorphic to $I^n$.

Comment: All right, we have $ S(( - \infty, 0]) = \{ 0_{\mathbb{R}^n} \} $. However,  the value of $S_{n}^{k = 0}(x)$  on $[0, 1]$ for $x = 0$ can be different of   $ 0_{\mathbb{R}^n}$. Thus $S$ is not well defined.

Comment: $S^0_n : I \to  \{ 0 \}$ is constant. Thus we have  $S((-\infty,1]) = \{ 0 \}$. On $[1,2]$ we have $S(x) = l^0_n(x)$ with a path connecting $S^0_n(1) = 0$ with $S^1_n(2)$.